# I am trying to print the longest word of a string, just the word itself. If it has equal words it prints the first one. Where am I messing up?

Tags: java, string

My output is just printing the whole string instead of the actual word.
I can't seem to find my mistake.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
String line = "";
String longString = "";
int max=0;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
if(line.length()>max){
   max=line.length();
   longString=line;
  }
}
  System.out.println(longString);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading lines and comparing their length. You don't consider words within a line.

A simple approach would be to take a line and to split it into bits by one or more space, as in `line.split("\\s+")`. That's your words.

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
  for (String word : line.split("\\s+")) {
    if (word.length() > max) {
      max = word.length();
      longString = word;
    }
  }
}
```